# run Linux applications on FreeBSD

Tags: linux, freebsd, application

is it possible at to run Linux applications on a FreeBSD machine? How can I do it? Thank in advance !

Comment: Read this: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu.html

Comment: You could use a Linux virtual machine on top of FreeBSD. What is the application you'd like to run?

Comment: As always, most FreeBSD questions are answered in The Handbook as linked to by @Bob . In most cases, there is a port/pkg of the same application from Linux available on FreeBSD.

Comment: FreeBSD has a Linux subsystem which does run Linux applications natively w/o a need to recompile. Read up on that on freebsd.org where there are plenty of resources.

Answer (score 2):

- **Ports/packages** There are tens of thousands of softwares in the ports/packages collection, installable and built from source on one's system in `/usr/ports/` (with options that one can configure to one's local system) or available as pre-built binaries from the FreeBSD package repositories.  It's quite likely that whatever you want to run has already been included.
- **Binary compatibility** There's a subsystem in the FreeBSD kernel that can emulate many Linux system calls and the Linux `/compat/linux/proc/` filesystem, although it deliberately does not provide some architecture-specific Linuxisms, for running Linux binaries.  In contrast, note, ports/packages are native FreeBSD programs, compiled tailored to FreeBSD and its libraries.

This is all documented in the *[FreeBSD Handbook](https://freebsd.org/doc/handbook/index.html)*.

OpenBSD and NetBSD have ports/packages systems, too.  NetBSD refers to it as just [the packages collection](https://netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html), because in NetBSD jargon "ports" are ports *of the operating system* to different platforms and architectures.  NetBSD has a similar binary compatibility layer, likewise documented in the *[NetBSD Guide](https://netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/index.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

If the source is available, try compiling it within FreeBSD. If not, use the Linux compatibility layer as others have mentioned.